# background task working permanently in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I am currently facing a problem. I am working on an mobile app made with Xamarin for Android and iOS. The app must work permanently even in background. But in the iOS version, the app is killed after 2 or 3 mins.

Previously, the app was using the Localisation API in order to run permanently. The problem is the battery consuming. Battery is down in 1 night which is not acceptable. And I can't use remote notifications because the devices will not be connected to Internet, only to local network

I have already done some researches and tests. I can't use background fetch (the app is still killed). I would like to avoid use of localisation. I saw a video about the local push connectivity feature made by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10113/) but I don't know if it has been implemented in Xamarin. I didn't find any information on that subject in Xamarin docs.

Do you know if it exist in Xamarin ? if not, do you have any other ideas ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: iOS does not let apps run "permanently" in the background.  There are a few specific categories of app that are allowed to have long running background tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jason. Yes I know that. Previously, the app was using the Localisation API in order to run permanently. The problem is the battery consuming. Battery is down in 1 night which is not acceptable. I have edited my question to add some informations. Previously, the app was using the Localisation API in order to run permanently. The problem is the battery consuming. Battery is down in 1 night which is not acceptable. And I can't use remote notifications because the devices will not be connected to Internet, only to local network.

Comment: "running permanently in the background" and "preserving battery" are conflicting requirements.

Comment: Yes I know but I have to manage with both of them

Comment: if you are given impossible requirements you need to push back against them, otherwise you are doomed to fail